# Built in (remove) function not working with function variable

Tags: python, if-statement, built-in

Have a good day everyone, pardon my lack of understanding, but I can't seem to figure out why python built in function does not work when being called with another function variable and it just doesn't do what I want at all. Here is the code

```
def ignoreten(h):
    ignoring = False
    for i in range (1,len(h)-2):
        if ignoring == True and h[i]==10:
            h.remove(10)
        if ignoring == False and h[i] ==10:
            ignoring = True
```

The basic idea of this is just to decided the first 10 in a list, keep it, continue iterating until you faced another 10, then just remove that 10 to avoid replication, I had searched around but can't seem to find any solution and that's why I have to bring it up here. Thank you

Comment: if `h = [1,2,10,3,4,10,5,6,10]`, what do you expect `h` to be after this function is called?

Comment: Hi @jedwards h should then be `[1,2,10,3,4,5,6,10]`, I did made the range to be `(1,len(h)-1)` first but it seem to run out of bound for some reason and I just changed it that way. It easier to just check for `if h[-1] =10` so I was trying to do it later instead

Comment: Just to be clear, if there are multiple occurrences, you want to remove only the second, right?  It's clear you want to leave the first, and your comment suggests you want to also leave any subsequent ones as-is.

Comment: `h.remove(10)` removes the *first* instance of the specified value that it finds.  And the work it does in finding that value is completely pointless, since you already *know* where the (un)desired 10 is!  Just use `del h[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you listed

```
def ignoreten(h):
    ignoring = False
    for i in range (1,len(h)-2):
        if ignoring == True and h[i]==10:
            h.remove(10)
        if ignoring == False and h[i] ==10:
            ignoring = True
```

Will actually do almost the *exact opposite* of what you want.  It'll iterate over `h` (sort of, see [1]), and if it finds 10 twice, it'll remove *the first* occurrence from the list.  (And, if it finds 10 three times, it'll remove *the first two* occurrences from the list.)

Note that `list.remove` will:

> Remove the ***first*** item from the list whose value is equal to x. It
> raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

Also note that you're mutating the list you're iterating over, so there's some additional weirdness here which may be confusing you, depending on your input.

From your follow-up comment to my question, it looks like you want to remove only the second occurrence of 10, not the first and not any subsequent occurrences.

Here are a few ways:

#### Iterate, store index, use `del`

```
def ignoreten(h):
    index = None
    found_first = False
    for i,v in enumerate(h):
        if v == 10:
            if not found_first:
                found_first = True
            else:
                index = i
                break

    if index is not None:
        del h[index]
```

A little more verbose than necessary, but explicit, safe, and modifiable without much fear.

Alternatively, you could delete inside the loop but you want to make sure you immediately break:

```
def ignoreten(h):
    found_first = False
    for i,v in enumerate(h):
        if v == 10:
            if not found_first:
                found_first = True
            else:
                del h[i]
                break
```

---

#### Collect indices of 10s, remove second

```
def ignoreten(h):
    indices = [i for (i,v) in enumerate(h) if v == 10]
    if len(indices) > 1:
        del h[indices[1]]  # The second index of 10 is at indices[1]
```

Clean, but will unnecessarily iterate past the second 10 and collect as many indices of 10s are there are.  Not likely a huge issue, but worth pointing out.

---

#### Collect indices of 10s, remove second (v2, from comments)

```
def ignoreten(h):
    indices = [i for (i,v) in enumerate(h) if v == 10]
    for i in reversed(indices[1:]):
        del h[i]
```

From your comment asking about removing all non-initial occurrences of 10, if you're looking for in-place modification of `h`, then you almost definitely want something like this.

The first line collects all the indices of 10 into a list.

The second line is a bit tricky, but working inside-out it:

- `[1:]` "throws out" the first element of that list (since you want to keep the first occurrence of 10)
- `reversed` iterates over that list backwards
- `del h[i]` removes the values at those indices.

The reason we iterate backwards is because doing so won't invalidate the rest of our indices that we've yet to delete.

In other words, if the list `h` was `[1, 10, 2, 10, 3, 10]`, our `indices` list would be `[1, 3, 5]`.

In both cases we skip 1, fine.

But if we iterate forwards, once we delete 3, and our list shrinks to 5 elements, when we go to delete 5 we get an `IndexError`.

Even if we didn't go out of bounds to cause an `IndexError`, our elements would shift and we'd be deleting incorrect values.

So instead, we iterate backwards over our indices, delete 5, the list shrinks to 5 elements, and index 3 is still valid (and still 10).

---

#### With `list.index`

```
def ignoreten(h):
    try:
        second_ten = h.index(10, h.index(10)+1)
        del h[second_ten]
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

The inner `.index` call finds the first occurrence, the second uses the [optional `begin` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to start searching after that.  Wrapped in try/except in case there are less than two occurrences.

---

**⇒ Personally, I'd prefer these in the opposite order of how they're listed.**

---

[1] You're iterating over a weird subset of the list with your arguments to `range`.  You're skipping (not applying your "is 10" logic to) the first and last two elements this way.

---

#### Bonus: Walrus abuse

(don't do this)

```
def ignoreten(h):
   x = 0
   return [v for v in h if v != 10 or (x := x + 1) != 1]
```

(unlike the previous versions that operated on h in-place, this creates a new list without the second occurrence of 10)

But the walrus operator is contentious enough already, please don't let this code out in the wild.  Really.

Comment: Absolutely love your explanations, it's so clear and efficient. However, I do have some question, in case I wanted to choose the iterate inside the loop method as you listed for the second answer, If I wanted to remove all occurrence after the first 10, all I would need is just to remove the break at the end if I understand it correctly?(lol. and I love the bonus explaination you just let out)

Comment: @VuongDuong, I wouldn't use that version then, because you're mutating the list you're iterating over and will inadvertently skip values.  In that case you almost definitely want a version of "collect indices of 10" -- I'll add the new version underneath it.

Comment: @VuongDuong see "Collect indices of 10s, remove second (v2, from comments)"

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help. Been working on this small project for a while and it just confused me so much.  Once again, thank you and please have a nice day!